# trouble displaying graphics in opengl program

Tags: c++, opengl

I am making changes in the code from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14154/OpenGL-Terrain-Generation-An-Introduction), to acomplish the same result without need the methods specific for Windows and be able to run the programa in other platforms. I can compile and run the program without errors (with the Main and Render functions listed below), but the result is a blank screen. Someone can find some reason in the code for this issue happen?

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // temp var's
    int width = 800;
    int height = 600;
    int bits = 32;

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(width,height);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutCreateWindow("Terrain");
    glutDisplayFunc(Render);
    glutReshapeFunc(AlteraTamanhoJanela);
    glutKeyboardFunc(GerenciaTeclado);
    glutMouseFunc(GerenciaMouse);
    Initialize();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Render:

```
void Render()
{
    radians =  float(PI*(angle-90.0f)/180.0f);

    // calculate the camera's position
    cameraX = lookX + sin(radians)*mouseY;     // multiplying by mouseY makes the
    cameraZ = lookZ + cos(radians)*mouseY;    // camera get closer/farther away with mouseY
    cameraY = lookY + mouseY / 2.0f;

    // calculate the camera look-at coordinates as the center of the terrain map
    lookX = (MAP_X*MAP_SCALE)/2.0f;
    lookY = 150.0f;
    lookZ = -(MAP_Z*MAP_SCALE)/2.0f;

    // clear screen and depth buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // set the camera position
    gluLookAt(cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    // set the current texture to the land texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, land);

    // we are going to loop through all of our terrain's data points,
    // but we only want to draw one triangle strip for each set along the x-axis.
    for (int z = 0; z < MAP_Z-1; z++)
    {
        //printf("%s %d\n","Loop FOR para Z = ",z);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for (int x = 0; x < MAP_X-1; x++)
        {
            //printf("%s %d\n","Loop FOR para X = ",x);
            // for each vertex, we calculate the grayscale shade color,
            // we set the texture coordinate, and we draw the vertex.
            /*
               the vertices are drawn in this order:

               0  ---> 1
                      /
                    /
                 |/
               2  ---> 3
            */

            // draw vertex 0
            //printf("%s\n","Primeiro");
            glColor3f(terrain[x][z][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z][1]/255.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(terrain[x][z][0], terrain[x][z][1], terrain[x][z][2]);

            // draw vertex 1
            //printf("%s\n","Segundo");
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glColor3f(terrain[x+1][z][1]/255.0f, terrain[x+1][z][1]/255.0f, terrain[x+1][z][1]/255.0f);
            glVertex3f(terrain[x+1][z][0], terrain[x+1][z][1], terrain[x+1][z][2]);

            // draw vertex 2
            //printf("%s\n","Terceiro");
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glColor3f(terrain[x][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z+1][1]/255.0f);
            glVertex3f(terrain[x][z+1][0], terrain[x][z+1][1], terrain[x][z+1][2]);

            // draw vertex 3
            //printf("%s\n","Quarto");
            glColor3f(terrain[x+1][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x+1][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x+1][z+1][1]/255.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(terrain[x+1][z+1][0], terrain[x+1][z+1][1], terrain[x+1][z+1][2]);
        }
        glEnd();
    }

    // enable blending
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    // enable read-only depth buffer
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);

    // set the blend function to what we use for transparency
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);

    // set back to normal depth buffer mode (writable)
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    // disable blending
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    glFlush();
    //SwapBuffers(g_HDC);           // bring backbuffer to foreground
}
```

Update: As requested, here is the other functions from my code.

```
void InitializeTerrain()
{
    // loop through all of the heightfield points, calculating
    // the coordinates for each point
    for (int z = 0; z < MAP_Z; z++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < MAP_X; x++)
        {
            terrain[x][z][0] = float(x)*MAP_SCALE;
            terrain[x][z][1] = (float)imageData[(z*MAP_Z+x)*3];
            terrain[x][z][2] = -float(z)*MAP_SCALE;
        }
    }
}

void CleanUp()
{
    free(imageData);
    free(landTexture);
}

// Initialize
// desc: initializes OpenGL
void Initialize()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);       // clear to black

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                       // use smooth shading
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                       // hidden surface removal
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);                        // do not calculate inside of poly's
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);                              // counter clock-wise polygons are out

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                       // enable 2D texturing

    imageData = LoadBitmapFile("terrain2.bmp", &bitmapInfoHeader);

    // initialize the terrain data and load the textures
    InitializeTerrain();
    LoadTextures();
}

// Função callback chamada quando o tamanho da janela é alterado
void AlteraTamanhoJanela(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
    int width, height;
    height = h;           // retrieve width and height
            width = w;

            if (height==0)                           // don't want a divide by zero
            {
                height=1;
            }

            glViewport(0, 0, width, height);       // reset the viewport to new dimensions
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);           // set projection matrix current matrix
            glLoadIdentity();                         // reset projection matrix

            // calculate aspect ratio of window
            gluPerspective(54.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,1.0f,1000.0f);

            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);         // set modelview matrix
            glLoadIdentity();                         // reset modelview matrix

}

// Função callback chamada para gerenciar eventos do mouse
void GerenciaMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    int oldMouseX, oldMouseY;
    // save old mouse coordinates
            oldMouseX = mouseX;
            oldMouseY = mouseY;

            // get mouse coordinates from Windows
            mouseX = x;
            mouseY = y;

            // these lines limit the camera's range
            if (mouseY < 200)
                mouseY = 200;
            if (mouseY > 450)
                mouseY = 450;

            if ((mouseX - oldMouseX) > 0)             // mouse moved to the right
                angle += 3.0f;
            else if ((mouseX - oldMouseX) < 0)     // mouse moved to the left
                angle -= 3.0f;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

/* Key press processing */
void GerenciaTeclado(unsigned char c, int x, int y)
{
    if(c == 27) exit(0);
}
```

And, finally, the content from file vkgllib.h, included by source code file above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define WINDOW_WIDTH    640             // Window Width  Default
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 480               // Window Height Default

// definition of PI
#define PI                      3.14159265

// Used to defien the title of the window
#define WINDOW_TITLE  "OpenGL Terrain Generation"

// A simple structure to define a point whose coordinates are integers
/*typedef struct { GLint x, y; } GLintPoint;

// This structure is used to store the vertices of a polyline
typedef struct { int num; GLintPoint pt[100]; } GLintPointArray;

// Data for an Icosahedron
#define ICO_X   0.525731112119133606
#define ICO_Z   0.850650808352039932*/

/*static GLfloat vdataICO[12][3] =
{
    { -ICO_X, 0.0, ICO_Z }, { ICO_X, 0.0, ICO_Z }, { -ICO_X, 0.0, -ICO_Z }, { ICO_X, 0.0, -ICO_Z },
    { 0.0, ICO_Z, ICO_X }, { 0.0, ICO_Z, -ICO_X }, { 0.0, -ICO_Z, ICO_X }, { 0.0, -ICO_Z, -ICO_X },
    { ICO_Z, ICO_X, 0.0 }, { -ICO_Z, ICO_X, 0.0 }, { ICO_Z, -ICO_X, 0.0 }, { -ICO_Z, -ICO_X, 0.0 }
};

static GLuint tindicesICO[20][3] =
{
    { 1, 4, 0 }, { 4, 9, 0 }, { 4, 5, 9 }, { 8, 5, 4 }, { 1, 8, 4 },
    { 1, 10, 8 }, { 10, 3, 8 }, { 8, 3, 5 }, { 3, 2, 5 }, { 3, 7, 2 },
    { 3, 10, 7 }, { 10, 6, 7 }, { 6, 11, 7 }, { 6, 0, 11 }, {6, 1, 0 },
    { 10, 1, 6 }, { 11, 0, 9 }, { 2, 11, 9 }, { 5, 2, 9 }, { 11, 2, 7 }
};*/

// Data for Tetrahedron
static GLfloat P1T[3] = { -2, 3, 0 }; 
static GLfloat P2T[3] = { -3, 0, 0 };
static GLfloat P3T[3] = { -1, 0, 3 }; 
static GLfloat P4T[3] = { -4, 0, 0 };

// Calculating the Normalized Cross Product of Two Vectors
void normalize( float v[3] )
{
    GLfloat d = sqrt( float(v[0]*v[0] + v[1]*v[1] + v[2]*v[2]) );
    if( d==0.0 )
    {
        cerr<<"zero length vector"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    v[0] /= d;
    v[1] /= d;
    v[2] /= d;
}

void normcrossprod( float v1[3], float v2[3], float out[3] )
{
    out[0] = v1[1]*v2[2] - v1[2]*v2[1];
    out[1] = v1[2]*v2[0] - v1[0]*v2[2];
    out[2] = v1[0]*v2[1] - v1[1]*v2[0];
    normalize( out );
}

////// Defines
#define BITMAP_ID 0x4D42              // the universal bitmap ID
#define MAP_X   32                       // size of map along x-axis
#define MAP_Z   32                       // size of map along z-axis
#define MAP_SCALE   20.0f                // the scale of the terrain map

////// Texture Information
BITMAPINFOHEADER    bitmapInfoHeader;   // temp bitmap info header
BITMAPINFOHEADER    landInfo;           // land texture info header
BITMAPINFOHEADER    waterInfo;          // water texture info header

//AUX_RGBImageRec
unsigned char*        imageData;           // the map image data
unsigned char*       landTexture;      // land texture data
unsigned int           land;                  // the land texture object

////// Terrain Data
float terrain[MAP_X][MAP_Z][3];     // heightfield terrain data (0-255); 256x256

// LoadBitmapFile
// desc: Returns a pointer to the bitmap image of the bitmap specified
//       by filename. Also returns the bitmap header information.
//         No support for 8-bit bitmaps.
unsigned char *LoadBitmapFile(char *filename, BITMAPINFOHEADER *bitmapInfoHeader)
{
    FILE *filePtr;                                // the file pointer
    BITMAPFILEHEADER    bitmapFileHeader;       // bitmap file header
    unsigned char       *bitmapImage;           // bitmap image data
    int                 imageIdx = 0;          // image index counter
    unsigned char       tempRGB;                   // swap variable

    // open filename in "read binary" mode
    filePtr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (filePtr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // read the bitmap file header
    fread(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, filePtr);

    // verify that this is a bitmap by checking for the universal bitmap id
    if (bitmapFileHeader.bfType != BITMAP_ID)
    {
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }

    // read the bitmap information header
    fread(bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, filePtr);

    // move file pointer to beginning of bitmap data
    fseek(filePtr, bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);

    // allocate enough memory for the bitmap image data
    bitmapImage = (unsigned char*)malloc(bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage);

    // verify memory allocation
    if (!bitmapImage)
    {
        free(bitmapImage);
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }

    // read in the bitmap image data
    fread(bitmapImage, 1, bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage, filePtr);

    // make sure bitmap image data was read
    if (bitmapImage == NULL)
    {
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }

    // swap the R and B values to get RGB since the bitmap color format is in BGR
    for (imageIdx = 0; imageIdx < bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage; imageIdx+=3)
    {
        tempRGB = bitmapImage[imageIdx];
        bitmapImage[imageIdx] = bitmapImage[imageIdx + 2];
        bitmapImage[imageIdx + 2] = tempRGB;
    }

    // close the file and return the bitmap image data
    fclose(filePtr);
    return bitmapImage;
}

bool LoadTextures()
{
    // load the land texture data
    landTexture = LoadBitmapFile("green.bmp", &landInfo);
    if (!landTexture)
        return false;

    // generate the land texture as a mipmap
    glGenTextures(1, &land);                  
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, land);       
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, landInfo.biHeight, landInfo.biWidth, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, landTexture);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I added the other functions from my code. Any sugestions? I still can't see why the program is compiled without errors, but nothing is displayed besides a blank screen.

Answer (score 2):

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You've asked for double-buffering.

And yet your `Render()` function seems to assume you're using single-buffering:

```
void Render()
{
    ...
    glFlush();
}
```

Either switch to `GLUT_SINGLE` or use `glutSwapBuffers()` instead of `glFlush()`.

Comment: I did that, and now, instead of a screen with a white background, i have a screen with a black background.